# How to redirect url when controller function argument is empty in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to redirect url when controller function argument is empty in codeigniter?

my controller give bellow

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

     public function resetpassword($passcode){
         if(!empty($passcode))
         {
             echo $passcode;
         }

        else
        {
             redirect(base_url());
        }
     }
}
```

When i hit url like `example.com/login/resetpassword/123456`

Result : `123456`  it is ok...!!

But when i hit url like `example.com/login/resetpassword/` it's produce error bellow

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for Login::resetpassword()

Filename: controllers/login.php

Line Number: 81
```

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your function resetpassword() needs a parameter, here $passcode

You can set a default value to prevent that error

```
public function resetpassword($passcode = NULL){
     if(!empty($passcode))
     {
         echo $passcode;
     }

    else
    {
         redirect(base_url());
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use this code

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

     public function resetpassword($passcode=''){
         if($passcode!='')
         {
             echo $passcode;
         }

        else
        {
             redirect(base_url());
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

         public function resetpassword($passcode=''){
             if(!empty($passcode))
             {
                 echo $passcode;
             }

            else
            {
                 redirect(base_url());
            }
         }
    }
```